# Golang name to zone lib

Tags: software-recommendations

Is there a lib (or api) that gives you a list of points that make a zone bound (circle, square or more complicated) when you give it a city name.

Given an iso city name (does this even exists?)

Ex:

Asking for 'Paris'

answer is :

- south: 40.2
- north: 41.44
- west: -74.7
- east: -72.69

I don't really care about the format

Comment: Marginally, it is still a vary broad question. Read this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066825/is-there-an-iso-standard-for-city-identification).